# can't stub class with NullableContextAttribute

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm using a third party library which has some classes I'm trying to mock using Rhino Mocks. When I attempt to create a stub for a class, I'm getting the following error. I cna't find a reference to what NullableContextAttribute is, but I assume it's related to specifying a nullable type on an event/delegate definition somewhere.  I can't figure out what an IAttributeDissassembler is.

I've read some solutions about using `AttributesToAvoidReplicating`, but I'm not sure what class to give it. `NullableContextAttribute` is not a class that can resolve to any namespace I can find.

I'm doing C#, .NET Framework 4.7.2. I tried changing my C# language level higher, but I think the nullable reference attribute is on something that is in c# 8 which I think I can't target with any .NET Framework?
.

```
        var myStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<SomeOtherClass>();


   Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerationException : There was an error trying to replicate non-inheritable attribute NullableContextAttribute using default attribute disassembler. Use custom implementation of IAttributeDisassembler (passed as 'AttributeDisassembler' property of ProxyGenerationOptions) to replicate this attribute.
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultAttributeDisassembler.Disassemble(Attribute attribute)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.DefineCustomAttribute(Attribute attribute, IAttributeDisassembler disassembler)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.ReplicateNonInheritableAttributes(Type targetType, ClassEmitter emitter)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateType(String newName, Type[] interfaces)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateCode(Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyType(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.MockClass(CreateMockState mockStateFactory, Type type, Type[] extras, Object[] argumentsForConstructor)
   at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.Stub(Type type, Object[] argumentsForConstructor)
   at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<GenerateStub>b__0(MockRepository repo)
   at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.CreateMockInReplay[T](Func`2 createMock)
   at
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is my dirty workaround. Since `NullableContextAttribute` is only for the compiler, you can't use it in source code [1](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md). But you can find this type in mocking assembly like this `Array.Find(typeof(SomeOtherClass).Assembly.GetTypes(), t => t.Name == "NullableContextAttribute")` where SomeOtherClass is what you are trying to mock. Found `Type` object you can pass to `Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.AttributesToAvoidReplicating.Add`.

I repeat, this is probably the worst solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Changing `GenerateStub` to `GenerateStrictMockWithRemoting` worked for me in a similar situation. You can try:

```cs
var myStub = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMockWithRemoting<SomeOtherClass>();
```

Don't have the explanation though for why it works.